# Scrapy empty xpath response

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

I'm trying to get the url of images from this url: https://www.iproperty.com.my/sale/all-residential/ .

Using Chrome extension Xpath Helper, I've identified the Xpath and used Scrapy Shell to get a response:

```
fetch("https://www.iproperty.com.my/sale/all-residential/")

response.xpath("//div[@class='cFwUMy']/div[@class='fUtkLG']/div[@class='slick-initialized slick-slider']/div[@class='slick-list']/div[@class='slick-track']/div[@class='slick-slide slick-active'][1]/div[@class='img-wrapper']/a/div[@class='cHKlDH']/img[@class='lazyautosizes lazyloaded']/@src")
```

However, it doesn't return anything.

I've also tried:

```
response.xpath("//div[@class='img-wrapper']/a/div[@class='cHKlDH']")
```

Still not working.

How do I get the url of the image from the page? I've been successful with getting the title, location, and price, but am stuck with getting the images.

EDIT1:

So weird, I tried

```
response.xpath("div[@class='img-wrapper']/a")
```

It returns the links as expected, but

```
response.xpath("div[@class='img-wrapper']/a/div[@class='cHKlDH']")
```

and

```
response.xpath("//div[@class='cHKlDH']")
```

simply refuses to return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrapy only downloads initial pages response

It does not executes an Javascript as our normal browser does.

Trick is, [disable Javascript](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-javascript-switcher/geddoclleiomckbhadiaipdggiiccfje?hl=en) in your browser and then check if your desired element exists or not

In the website mentioned above, they have image links in JSON format in their initial page response and after that

In scrapy, you can do

```
re.findall(r"window.__INITIAL_STATE__ =(.*)window.__RENDER_APP_ERROR__", response.body, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

It will return you this JSON code, https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=bbef330441b24957aeaceedcea621ba7

`listings > items` key, it has all data, prices/images you need

Here is complete working Python code

https://repl.it/@UmairAyub/AdmirableHilariousSpellchecker

Comment: Ah you're right, disabled javascript and the images don't load. Could you clarify the code? Should I run it in the shell? And how would I implement it in my spider?

Comment: the above regex will return you the JSON string, then load that into Python Dict and then get data what you want

Comment: Sorry I'm totally clueless on this, I copy and pasted the code into scrapy shell, but got an error.

Comment: create scrape project and then in the callback function, do `logging.info( the regex I provided)` and you will see what I am talking about, you seems very new to Python, you will have to work hard :P

Comment: Yes I have no prior experience with Python. I've gotten the JSON response, but now I need to filter to only get the image URL and associate the URL with each listing. How would I do that?

Comment: do `json.loads(your_response_here)` and then it will return you a Dictionary or Associative Array if you are from a PHP background, and then iterate over its elements in a for loop

Comment: I'm getting`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'` , I read the json.loads() is expecting string as its parameter and the response is in JSON right?

Comment: Sorry the error is `TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: @AmirAsyraf https://repl.it/@UmairAyub/AdmirableHilariousSpellchecker is complete working code

Comment: Thank you very much @Umair ,you've helped me so much! Seems like a much better way to scrape the website too.e

Comment: Hi @Umair, how does the regex you provided work? This one:

`re.findall(r"window.__INITIAL_STATE__ =(.*)window.__RENDER_APP_ERROR__", response.body, flags=re.DOTALL)`

Does it only work on websites using React?

Comment: `window.__INITIAL_STATE__ =(.*)window.__RENDER_APP_ERROR__` means get string between `window.__INITIAL_STATE__ =` and `window.__RENDER_APP_ERROR__` ....